# Show that $AA_4\cap BB_4\cap CC_4\neq\emptyset$

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ a triangle inscribed în The circle $\Gamma$. The bisector of $\angle BAC$ intersecta $BC$ în $A'$ and $\Gamma$ în $A_1$. Let $AA_2\perp BC, A_2\in BC$ and $A_1A_2\cap \Gamma=\{A_1,A_3\}$, $A_3A'\cap\Gamma=\{A_3,A_4\}$. We define in the same way $B_4$ and $C_4$. Show that $AA_4\cap BB_4\cap CC_4\neq\emptyset$.

I have no idea how to start. This is my picture. I am sorry because I don't know to draw în Geogebra. [image]